# SUPEE 6788 - hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml

Tags: patch, magento-1.9

Im installing the Magento SUPPEE 6788 patch but its giving this error only:

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml.rej
```

Running Magento 1.9.1.0

I've replaced this file (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml) with one from a new installation but the same error is given.

I've opened the resetforgottenpassword.phtml.rej file but its empty.

Any ideas what I can do?

Full response is:

```
[root@store htdocs]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
can't find file to patch at input line 38
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git .htaccess.sample .htaccess.sample
|index b8821af..383313a 100644
|--- .htaccess.sample
|+++ .htaccess.sample
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `.htaccess.sample` file in your root directory. You can get one from a clean magento installtion codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I placed the .htassecc.sample file from a new installation but the same error is given as my first post.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the server is running on Nginx, so no htaccess file is read.

Comment: @user2864591 If you put a clean `.htaccess` file (not sample) in to the root directory and rerun, does it still give an error? Make a backup before doing this, and do it on a test version if possible before production

Comment: the error message says that it can't find `.htaccess.sample` so I think we need to start there

Comment: All no luck so far.. thanks for suggestions - I disnt notice the .htaccess.sample bit. Both this and a fresh .htaccess file are in the site root but its giving the same error.

Comment: @user2864591 other than checking the folder location (ensure both of those ht files are under `yoursite.com/` and you run the sh command from within `yoursite.com/` (not from htdocs) I can't think of anything else, sorry

Comment: Thanks user2864591, yes both files are in site root and also runnign sh from same location.

Answer (score 0):

Since .htaccess.sample isn't needed, you could just remove this part from your patch. 
It's dirty, but it'll work.

Open your patch file in a text-editor and find the following:

```
diff --git .htaccess.sample .htaccess.sample
```

Remove everythig from this line until

```
+    </Files>
```

Save the patch file and try running it again.